# Removing email from GitHub also removed commits

Tags: github

I have 2 emails associated with my Github account, one primary email, and one secondary. When I remove my secondary email from account, almost half of my commits are gone.

How can I persist my commits when removing my secondary email address?

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue. Have you been added to some organization by your secondary email, and removing it, lost the access?

Comment: GitHub can't remove your commits without corrupting your git repo (which seems highly unlikely that this occurred). What evidence do you have that the commits are missing? Most likely GitHub just doesn't know those commits are yours any longer since you removed the email address that identifies them from your GitHub account. Do a `git log` locally and look at the commit ids that used your removed email address. Now go check the commit history on GitHub to confirm those commit ids still exist.

Comment: I not in any organization. My contribution graph shows 603 commits, but after I remove the secondary email, it shows about 300 commits in the last year. The commits still exists, but they're not associated with my account.

Comment: GitHub use the email addresses to do the associating. Keep them and the commits stay associated; remove an email address and the commits are no longer associated. Note that this has nothing to do with *Git:* it's purely a *GitHub* thing.

Comment: Note that there has been some talk about having fancier ways to do the association, since once a commit exists it can never be changed, but the email address *in* that commit (e.g., "corporate123@corp.corp") might refer to Bob for 2012-2021 and then to Alice for 2022-2031. But right now it's one-email-maps-to-one-particular-user.