# How can i change my git email without losing history?

Tags: git, github

I have a problem with Git commits.
I am not shown as contributor on my GitHub account in a private repository.I think it is because i get a different email address, than my GitHub account,with the git config user.email command.
I committed in these months with that email, is there a way to transfer past commits ,history etc... to my GitHub account?

Comment: Try the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919878/git-rewrite-previous-commit-usernames-and-emails) and see if it helps.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71821971

Answer (score 1):

You can have [multiple email addresses](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account) associated with your GitHub account. If you add the email address to your account and it meets all the other [GitHub criteria](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile) then the commits should be associated with your account.

Alternatively, you can [rewrite your commits to use a different email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919878/git-rewrite-previous-commit-usernames-and-emails).